# Unit Testing: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

So, I am trying to Unit Test my project, and the UnitTests.cs file has 8 tests, out of which 6 pass but 2 fail, the two that fail gives me the error of "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext." the **UnitTests.cs** file:

```
private readonly CatalogItemContext _context;

private Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder<CatalogItemContext> obj;

public UnitTests()
{
    obj = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CatalogItemContext>();
    _context = new CatalogItemContext(obj.Options);
}

[Fact]
public void Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllItems()
{
    CatalogController cc = new CatalogController(_context);
    var test = cc.GetItems().Result;
    var okResult = test.Result as OkObjectResult;

    var items = Assert.IsType<List<CatalogItem>>(okResult.Value);
    Assert.Equal(3, items.Count);
}

[Fact]
public void Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllProductsTypes()
{
    CatalogController cc = new CatalogController(_context);
    var test = cc.GetTypes().Result;
    var okResult = test.Result as OkObjectResult;
    var Expected = typeof(OkObjectResult);
    var items = Assert.IsType<List<CatalogType>>(okResult.Value);
    Assert.Equal(3, items.Count);
}
```

My **Startup.cs** contains the following:

```
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

services.AddDbContext<CatalogItemContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

And **Context File** is as follows:

```
public class CatalogItemContext : DbContext
{
    public CatalogItemContext(DbContextOptions<CatalogItemContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<CatalogItem> CatalogItem { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CatalogType> CatalogType { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("Catalog");
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CatalogTypeEntityTypeConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CatalogItemEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }     
}


public class CatalogContextDesignFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<CatalogItemContext>
{
    public CatalogItemContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder =  new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CatalogItemContext>()
            .UseSqlServer("--REDACTED CONNECTION STRING--",
            x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationHistory", "catalog"));

        return new CatalogItemContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
```

Can someone please shed some light on what I can do to make it work?

EDIT: Error which are appearing:
PS: I am using VSCode.

```
    [xUnit.net 00:00:01.26]     UnitTests.Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllProductsTypes [FAIL]

[xUnit.net 00:00:01.27]     UnitTests.Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllItems [FAIL]

  X UnitTests.Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllProductsTypes [2ms]
  Error Message:
   System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext 
is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.)
---- System.InvalidOperationException : No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
  Stack Trace:
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at UnitTests.Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllProductsTypes() in --Location redacted--\Test\UnitTests.cs:line 33
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider scopedProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IAsyncEnumerableAccessor<TEntity>.get_AsyncEnumerable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions.Internal.QueryableExtensions.AsAsyncEnumerable[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at --Redacted--.Controllers.CatalogController.GetTypes() in --Location Redacted--\src\--Redacted--\Controllers\CatalogController.cs:line 43

  X UnitTests.Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllItems [2ms]
  Error Message:
   System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext 
is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.)
---- System.InvalidOperationException : No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
  Stack Trace:
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at UnitTests.Get_WhenCalled_ReturnsAllItems() in --Location Redacted--\src\--Redacted--\Test\UnitTests.cs:line 22
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider scopedProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IAsyncEnumerableAccessor<TEntity>.get_AsyncEnumerable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions.Internal.QueryableExtensions.AsAsyncEnumerable[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at --Redacted--.Controllers.CatalogController.GetItems() in --Location Redacted--\src\Redacted\Controllers\CatalogController.cs:line 32


Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 8
     Passed: 6
     Failed: 2
 Total time: 2.1150 Seconds
```

Comment: A unit test would not test your database directly. If testing a controller, then you would move you DB logic to a different class and mock out that object. Then you are testing the controller in isolation and asserting the different responses given the mock data. If you want to test the controller integration with the DB, then this is a integration test.

Comment: Can you also provide the error you are receiving?

Comment: Added Error in the edit.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you should never call .Result on a Task . Instead, define your tests as async Task and use await to retrieve value from Task. This explains how : http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2012/11/UnitTestingAsynchronousMethodsUsingMSTestAndXUnit.html

Comment: what you are doing is not unit testing

Answer (score 2):

Compare these two pieces of code :

```
obj = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CatalogItemContext>();
_context = new CatalogItemContext(obj.Options);
```

and

```
var optionsBuilder =  new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CatalogItemContext>()
    .UseSqlServer("--REDACTED CONNECTION STRING--",
    x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationHistory", "catalog"));

return new CatalogItemContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

One has something the other is missing.

Also note that the code in Startup.cs is never involved in execution of your tests. I recommend putting breakpoints in code in Startup.cs and in `CatalogContextDesignFactory.CreateDbContext` and see if they are hit when you debug the tests.